# XSLT Namespace Unable to read ns0:

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am a complete newbie to XML and XSLT transformation. I have created an XSLT file which correctly translates an XML file I am given by a customer, but it only does so if I remove the ns0 lines - as I have no control of the file I receive I need to be able to read the file with the ns0 lines retained, I've looked at several questions that have been answered that seem to relate to the same issue but I'm such a newbie I'm struggling to understand how the answers might apply to my problem, details as follows :-

XML File starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ns0:MyRecord xmlns:ns0="https://some/kind/of/text">
```

AND ENDS WITH ns0:MyRecord

I have written an XSLT (Shown below) to transform the XML, it only works if i remove the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">               

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<ImportJobs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <description>Jobs Import Test</description>
  <copyright>© A Software Company Ltd 2015</copyright>
  <Exceptions></Exceptions>
  <DataItems>
    <xsl:for-each select="MyRecord/ImportJobs/DataItems/Job">
      <Job>
        <CustomerAlpha>
          <xsl:text>AnAccountNo</xsl:text>
        </CustomerAlpha>
        <SiteAlpha>
          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </SiteAlpha>
        <EquipNo>
          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </EquipNo>
        <Authority>
          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </Authority>
        <Reference>
          <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        </Reference>
    <UserRef2>
          <xsl:value-of select="JobNumber"/>
        </UserRef2>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </DataItems>

</ImportJobs>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I Think I should add xmlns:ns0="https://some/kind/of/text" but even when I do it does not allow the XSLT to see the data

Whatever I try I only get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportJobs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <description>Jobs Import Test</description>
  <copyright>© A Software Company Ltd 2015</copyright>
  <Exceptions />
  <DataItems />
</ImportJobs>
```

Comment: Text above should say "It only works if I remove the ns0 lines from the supplied XML it is seeking to process

Comment: It's better to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42582626/edit) your question rather than just add a comment (that could be deleted, and is less visible anyway).

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MyRecord/ImportJobs/DataItems/Job">
```

selects nothing, because the `MyRecord` element is in a namespace. In order to select it, you need to declare the same namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix in the *select* expression - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="https://some/kind/of/text"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ImportJobs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <!-- ... -->
        <DataItems>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:MyRecord/ImportJobs/DataItems/Job">
                <!-- ... -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </DataItems>
    </ImportJobs>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the descendant nodes - `ImportJobs`, `DataItems` and `Job` - are not in a namespace - otherwise they too require a prefix.

Comment: Many Thanks Michael.hor257k you have solved my problem